# How to sort bars by boolean value in d3?

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js, graph

I have a csv. Each row in the csv contains data among which are the boolean fields :`is_first`, `is_second`, `is_third`.
I'm creating bar graphs using the data (one bar corresponding to each row), and I want the bars to be sorted, from left to right, based on the boolean fields. I want all the rows with `is_first == true` to be displayed together on the leftmost section of the graph, I want the the rows with `is_second == true` to be displayed together to the right of the `is_first` group, and I want the `is_third == true` rows to be displayed together to the right of the `is_second` group (ie on the rightmost side of the graph). How can I do this with `d3.sort()`

Answer (score -1):

There is no `d3.sort` it is the `Array.sort`

```
function col2num(d) {
    if (d.is_first) return 1;
    if (d.is_second) return 2;
    return 3;
}

function sortByIs(a, b) {
   return col2num(a) - col2num(b);
}

var datasort = data.sort(sortByIs);
```